# Address Label Missing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

My Magento website is not displaying the Address field in the check out page.
When I inspect it with google the label does exist but its not visible.
I researched a lot about it but I'm not sure where this form is being rendered.
Any suggestions?

I check the shipping html file but I didn't see how can I override it.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

And this is the code for that page:

```
<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
<div class="step-title" translate="'Shipping Address'" data-role="title" />
<div id="checkout-step-shipping"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">

    <each if="!quoteIsVirtual" args="getRegion('customer-email')" render="" />
    <each args="getRegion('address-list')" render="" />
    <each args="getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses')" render="" />

    <!-- Address form pop up -->
    <if args="!isFormInline">
        <div class="new-address-popup">
            <button type="button"
                    class="action action-show-popup"
                    click="showFormPopUp"
                    visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                <span translate="'New Address'" />
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
             visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
             render="shippingFormTemplate" />
    </if>

    <each args="getRegion('before-form')" render="" />

    <!-- Inline address form -->
    <render if="isFormInline" args="shippingFormTemplate" />
</div>
</li>

<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
class="checkout-shipping-method"
data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
role="presentation">
<div class="checkout-shipping-method">
    <div class="step-title"
         translate="'Shipping Methods'"
         data-role="title" />

    <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-method-form')" render="" />

    <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content"
         role="tabpanel"
         aria-hidden="false">
        <form id="co-shipping-method-form"
              class="form methods-shipping"
              if="rates().length"
              submit="setShippingInformation"
              novalidate="novalidate">

            <render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"/>

            <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                <each args="getRegion('shippingAdditional')" render="" />
            </div>
            <div role="alert"
                 if="errorValidationMessage().length"
                 class="message notice">
                <span text="errorValidationMessage()" />
            </div>
            <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action                 continue primary">
                        <span translate="'Next'" />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="no-quotes-block"
             ifnot="rates().length > 0"
             translate="'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is photo of the checkout page:

[image: label]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.
Using google inspect I realized that when it's rendering the address field, for the address label instead of rendering:

```
<label class="label">
    <span data-bind="i18n: element.label">Morada</span>
</label>
```

it's rendering:

```
<legend class="label">
    <span data-bind="i18n: element.label">Morada</span>
</legend>
```

So after I inspected the code, I came across a page called group.html and changed the legend to label, and now it's working correctly.

Here is the faulty code in case anyone experienced a similar issue. Just change the legend to label, and that's it!

group.html file:

```
<fieldset class="field" data-bind="css: additionalClasses">
<legend class="label">
    <span translate="element.label"></span>
</legend>
<div class="control">
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->

        <!-- ko if: element.visible() -->

            <!-- ko ifnot: (element.input_type == 'checkbox' ||          element.input_type == 'radio') -->
                <!-- ko template: $parent.fieldTemplate --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if: (element.input_type == 'checkbox' ||         element.input_type == 'radio') -->
                <!-- ko template: element.elementTmpl --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: validateWholeGroup -->
    <!-- ko  foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko if: element.error() && element.visible() -->
            <label class="error" data-bind="attr: { for: uid }, text:       element.error"></label>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
  </fieldset>
```